# Deactivate Stack Overflow Account

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts, unregistered-users

I have a Stack Overflow account with name [NeverHopeless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751527/neverhopeless). I mistakenly created another account with the same name when I was posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437362/how-to-get-first-and-last-date-of-current-year/13438806#13438806).

These are the steps I followed and the account created:

1. When I posted a solution, system asked me to login.
2. I logged in with `gmail` address. ( Don't know if previously it were `googlemail` or whatelse)
3. redirected to captcha.
4. Provided values and Instead of posted with existing account system has created the new one.

I usually use this to log into my account:

> [image]

My question is: **How can I deactivate my new account which has 1 score for now**?

Comment: how can I merge them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I think you did not log in.

In the screen:

> > [image]

You missed the concept of "or". You should **either** click the "log in" link, log in with OpenID provider then answer the question while logged in, **or** type your name and email manually and by that creating brand new **unregistered account**.

What happened in my opinion is that you typed your existing email and name but the system does not perform any check, and it created unregistered account for you.

In the [Merge user profiles page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge), click the "click here" link in "If you have lost access to your duplicate account, please click here to fill out the form" and fill the details, your accounts should be merged when moderator will handle it.

Comment: You are right. I did the same. Also, I have already followed the steps you are talking about and waiting for the response. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: thank you for your response!

Comment: Cheers, I see it was handled by now.

Answer (score 5):

Merge your accounts using the instructions on https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-logins, I am unable to see any X's ? what does it mean it refers to my main account ?

Comment: You need to log into your main account and *add* the duplicate login to that account. The `(x)` boxes are only used for *removing* logins. Don't do that.

Comment: thank you for your response, I have accepted second answer since it was much closer than the issue i was facing. +1 for you too.